# Are there any synchronization issue when it's used two counters and one clock, all of them working in a different Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, counter, clock

i need two counters to work like a chess clock. When the first one starts the second stops. When the second starts the fisrt one stop.
In parallel with these two counters i need another clock which never stops.

I am trying to do it. I created two counters and it works fine but when i create a new thread(3 Threads in total), which will run the clock, it causes some problem(increment both counters at the same time).

Does these problem have something related with  synchronization problem? Why does it run correctedly for 2 Threads but not for three?

```
//////////////////////////////// HOW THE OBJECTS ARE CREATED /////////////////////////

private Relogio relogioBranco, relogioPreto;
private RelogioGeral relogioGeral;

relogioBranco = new Relogio(relogioBrancoLabel);
relogioPreto = new Relogio(relogioPretoLabel);
relogioGeral= new RelogioGeral(relogioPretoLabel,menu);
new Thread(relogioBranco).start();
new Thread(relogioPreto).start();
new Thread(relogioGeral).start();

relogioBranco.rodarRelogio(false);
relogioPreto.rodarRelogio(false);
relogioGeral.rodarRelogio(true);

////////////////////////////////////// COUNTERS //////////////////////////////
// The clock will be used to autosave my game every 1 minute

package Janela;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Relogio implements Runnable, Serializable {

    private volatile AtomicInteger segundo, minuto, hora;
    private JLabel relogioLabel;
    private boolean relogioRodando;

    public Relogio(JLabel relogio) {
        segundo = new AtomicInteger();
        minuto =  new AtomicInteger();
        hora =  new AtomicInteger();

        minuto.set(0);
        hora.set(0);
        segundo.set(0);
        minuto.set(0);
        this.relogioLabel = relogio;
    }

    public void rodarRelogio(boolean rodar) {
        relogioRodando = rodar;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if (relogioRodando) {
                    segundo.incrementAndGet();
                    if (segundo.intValue() == 60) {
                        segundo.set(0);
                        minuto.incrementAndGet();
                        if (minuto.intValue() == 60) {
                            minuto.set(0);
                            hora.incrementAndGet();
                            if (hora.intValue() == 24) {
                                segundo.set(0);
                                minuto.set(0);
                                hora.set(0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    String tempo = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hora.intValue(), minuto.intValue(), segundo.intValue());
                    relogioLabel.setText(tempo);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("EXCEÇÃO INTERRUPTED EXCEPTION");
        }
    }
}


///////////////////////////////////////////// CLOCK ///////////////////////////////////

package Janela;

import MesaTabuleiro.ArrayPecas;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RelogioGeral implements Runnable, Serializable {

private volatile AtomicInteger segundo, minuto, hora;
private final JLabel relogioLabel;
private boolean relogioRodando;

public RelogioGeral(JLabel relogio, Menu menu) {
    segundo = new AtomicInteger();
    minuto = new AtomicInteger();
    hora = new AtomicInteger();

    segundo.set(0);
    minuto.set(0);
    hora.set(0);
    this.relogioLabel = relogio;
}

public void rodarRelogio(boolean rodar) {
    relogioRodando = rodar;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if (relogioRodando) {
                segundo.incrementAndGet();
                if (segundo.intValue() == 60) {
                    segundo.set(0);
                    minuto.incrementAndGet();
                    if (minuto.intValue() == 60) {
                        minuto.set(0);
                        hora.incrementAndGet();
                        if (hora.intValue() == 24) {
                            segundo.set(0);
                            minuto.set(0);
                            hora.set(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
                String tempo = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hora.intValue(), minuto.intValue(), segundo.intValue());
                relogioLabel.setText(tempo);
                if (minuto.intValue() %1 == 1) {
                    saveGame();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        System.out.println("EXCEÇÃO INTERRUPTED EXCEPTION");
    }
}

public void saveGame() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " 1 Minuto de Partida. Salvando Jogo.");
    FileOutputStream output;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream("jogo.ser");
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(output);

        oos.writeObject(ArrayPecas.getInst().getPecasPretas());
        oos.writeObject(ArrayPecas.getInst().getPecasBrancas());
        oos.writeObject(ArrayPecas.getInst().getxPerdePr());
        oos.writeObject(ArrayPecas.getInst().getyPerdePr());
        oos.writeObject(ArrayPecas.getInst().getxPerdeBr());
        oos.writeObject(ArrayPecas.getInst().getyPerdeBr());

        oos.writeObject(TelaMenuJogo.getTela().getXequeVsbl());
        oos.writeObject(TelaMenuJogo.getTela().getXequeMateVsbl());
        oos.writeObject(TelaMenuJogo.getTela().getHistoricoTxt());
        oos.writeObject(TelaMenuJogo.getTela().getJaDesenhou());
        oos.writeObject(TelaMenuJogo.getTela().getLinha());
        oos.writeObject(TelaMenuJogo.getTela().getColuna());
        oos.writeObject(TelaMenuJogo.getTela().getLinPecaSel());
        oos.writeObject(TelaMenuJogo.getTela().getColPecaSel());
        oos.writeObject(TelaMenuJogo.getTela().getQtdJogadas());
        oos.writeObject(TelaMenuJogo.getTela().getJogador());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Arquivo nao encontrado");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao tentar gravar no arquivo de saida");
    } finally {
        if (oos != null) {
            try {
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao fechar arquivo de saida");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think you don't need two threads for the two counters. Instead you could have one single thread that alternately iterates the counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you pass the same label to the main clock as to one of the others:

```
relogioBranco = new Relogio(relogioBrancoLabel);
relogioPreto = new Relogio(relogioPretoLabel);
relogioGeral= new RelogioGeral(relogioPretoLabel,menu);
```

Shouldn't it have its own label?

I think this problem has nothing to do with concurrency. You will only get concurrency problems if two threads are working one resource (e.g. thread a and thread b are both reading the same field). This is not the case here. Every thread works on his own variables/objects.